# cheese fondue not binding

Tags: cheese, wine

I am planning on making a cheese fondue this weekend.

How ever last time I made it the cheese (Emmental and gruyere) wouldn't fully disolve into the wine base. It basically was a winey sauce with stringy cheese in it. Aside from the wine (reisling) and cheese the pot was rubbed with a garlic clove and it called for a little lemon and kirsh and a bit of corn flour for thickening.

When I had fondue at a restaurant last time the sauce was a lovely consistency and stuck to the bread nicely without stringy pieces of cheese.

Comment: Try swapping some Fribourg Vacherin cheese for the Emmental - it's nice and creamy and the standard for a 50/50 fondue here in Switzerland 8) Use a medium heat to melt - you don't want to burn the cheese!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stringy or seized cheese in a fondue can often be caused by overheating or too little acid.  Using a dry wine may reduce the need for any additional acid.

A good method for a simple cheese fondue is as follows:

1. prepare the pot
2. mix the wine and starch then bring to temperature over medium heat.
3. add cheese and stir continuously for 10-15 minutes until smooth.
4. season with lemon juice (optional), nutmeg, etc.
5. keep warm, but do not boil.

Comment: Thankyou. Maybe I let it get too hot then that may be the answer in my case. I think when it gets stringy I try to 'fix' it by heating it even hotter. I will try a cooler approach this time :)